# auto refresh json without reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

i am trying to make an auto refresh json which is reloading for changes every 5 seconds. It loads perfectly first time on load but my setinterval is not working correctly. It goes of every 5 seconds but it doesnt update my menu even though changes has been made? .

Here is what i got so far:

```
 $(document).ready(function(load) {

    var dmJSON = "example.com";

    $.getJSON( dmJSON, function(data) {


    setInterval(function () {
      $(news).html(""); 
      $.getJSON();         
    }, 5000);

    var html = '';

 // loop through all the news items, and append the 
 // title and published date to the html variable.

 for(var i = 0; i < data.feed.data.length; i++){

    html += '<div style="width: 600;direction: rtl;background-color: white;padding: 12px 12px 0;border: 1px solid;border-color: #e5e6e9 #dfe0e4 #d0d1d5;border-radius: 4px;margin-bottom: 20px;color: black;">';

    html += '<span style="/* text-align: left; */direction: rtl;position: absolute;left: 250px;"> ' + data.feed.data[i].created_time + ' </span><span><img alt="" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/gakuseisean/ivista-2/128/Network-Globe-Disconnected-icon.png" style="background-size:auto;background-repeat: no-repeat;display: inline-block;height: 20px;width: 20px;position: absolute;left: 490px;padding-top: 9px;" /></span>' ;

    html += '<br>' ;

    html += data.feed.data[i].message ;

    html += '<p><img alt="" src=' + data.feed.data[i].picture + ' /></p>';

    html += '</div>';

 }

 // append all the html variable to the ticker div.
    $("#news").append(html);
 });

 });
```

i use this code but when refresh he give my empty page

```
setInterval(function () {
  $(news).html(""); 
  $.getJSON();         
}, 5000);
```

Comment: `var dmJSON = "https://";` why is url empty?

Comment: I think you need to call getJSON with arguments. In your setInterval callback you are calling it without any argument.

Comment: @JohnnyAW i have the url but am delete

Comment: ach ok, could write something like `example.com`

Comment: Also, why are you setting the interval inside the getJSON callback as well? setInterval, unlike setTimeout, will repeat the callback function call every n seconds.

Comment: well, it's here in the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/ - if you want to call it repeatedly, put it in another function and call that (an answer showing you how just popped up in the meantime)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(load) {

 var dmJSON = "https://";
 function fetch() {
   $.getJSON( dmJSON + (+new Date()), function(data) {
     $("#news").html('');
     var html = '';

     // loop through all the news items, and append the 
     // title and published date to the html variable.

     for(var i = 0; i < data.feed.data.length; i++){

         html += '<div style="width: 600;direction: rtl;background-color: white;padding: 12px 12px 0;border: 1px solid;border-color: #e5e6e9 #dfe0e4 #d0d1d5;border-radius: 4px;margin-bottom: 20px;color: black;">';

         html += '<span style="/* text-align: left; */direction: rtl;position: absolute;left: 250px;"> ' + data.feed.data[i].created_time + ' </span><span><img alt="" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/gakuseisean/ivista-2/128/Network-Globe-Disconnected-icon.png" style="background-size:auto;background-repeat: no-repeat;display: inline-block;height: 20px;width: 20px;position: absolute;left: 490px;padding-top: 9px;" /></span>' ;

         html += '<br>' ;

         html += data.feed.data[i].message ;

         html += '<p><img alt="" src=' + data.feed.data[i].picture + ' /></p>';

         html += '</div>';

      }

      // append all the html variable to the ticker div.
      $("#news").append(html);
   });
 }
 setInterval(fetch, 5000);// call fetch every 5 seconds
 fetch(); // call fetch first time
});
```

Comment: sounds good, but I would empty html after the data is arrived, not before json-call

Comment: Also, check the API call status code and response. Status code 304 indicates a cached response. To explicitly clear it you can do one thing. In the URL that you are hitting append the timestamp parameter every time the call happens. This will ensure that the call response is not cached.

Comment: @JohnnyAW his work , and am waiting to see the new update without reload

Comment: @aligassan it will work, but you may have several seconds empty screen, until ajax got you the data